# checking if a user is in a specific child for login firebase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I am making an android application using Firebase database and I want to check that the user is not in registered as an "Association" so I am checking if he belongs to the child "Association".
The method userLogin is supposed to not log in the user if he is under the child "Associations" and log in him otherwise.
However, it is not working and the user is logged in even if he is under "Associations"

```
    private void userLogin() {
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();



    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String RegisteredUserID = currentUser.getUid();

                DatabaseReference jLoginDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Associations").child(RegisteredUserID);

                jLoginDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            finish();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInDonor.this, homedonor.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }



            }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }});}
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not tried this, but it should work, first, after you log in with a user and enters inside `task.isSuccessful` ,  you can retrieve the current logged in user with `task.getResult().getUser().getUid()`. Then just loop inside Associations and get each user key (I assume that Associations has userIDs inside as nodes with a certain value), then compare if the current logged in user is equal to one inside that node, if matchs it will pop up your Toast, if not you will be redirected.

Try this

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    DatabaseReference jLoginDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Associations");

                    jLoginDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                             if(snapshot.getKey().equals(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                finish();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInDonor.this, homedonor.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                       }
```

I used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` because we only need to loop once at the reference and not keep listening for data